# Setting a object with "Assign" property to nil

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

If I am having a variable defined with "Assign" property then is it ok to setting them to nil in dealloc method?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id test;

- (void)dealloc {
    self.test = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to release the ivar directly. If a subclass overrides the setter methods of a property, your object might leak because your setter is not called. Consider:

```
@interface ClassA
@property (readwrite, retain) id anObject;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize anObject;

- (void)dealloc {
    self.anObject = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
@end

@implementation ClassB
- (void)setAnObject: (id)anObject {
    // do nothing!
}
@end
```

Instances of ClassB will leak `anObject`!

Comment: +1 this is correct.  It's always better to `release` the ivar directly in `dealloc`.

Comment: What if I am not using "Retain" rather using "Assign". Do I still need to set it to "nil" in dealloc?

Comment: If you're using `assign`, it doesn't matter. If you're using `retain` or `copy`, you must take care to release it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Depends *how* you do it, if you do it via the property setter (not recommended), then yes.

If you do direct assignment, then **no, because the retained object will leak.**

So this is fine:

```
- (void) dealloc {
   self.test = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

But this is a **no-go**:

```
- (void) dealloc {
   test = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

My advice is to just send the `release` message to all of your retained ivars in `-dealloc`, this will work nicely because if `test` happens to be `nil`, then nothing will happen.

Trust me. Send `release` directly in `-dealloc`. That is all.

```
- (void) dealloc {
   [test release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't call the setter, so it leaks the object rather than releasing it.

Comment: What if I am not using "Retain" rather using "Assign". Do I still need to set it to "nil" in dealloc?