# Why I don't have memory leak with [anObject release], while I have a problems with self.anObject = nil?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I copied this example from this topic. [It's better to release the ivar directly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741808/setting-a-object-with-assign-property-to-nil)

> It's better to release the ivar directly. If a subclass overrides the
>   setter methods of a property, your object might leak because your
>   setter is not called.

```
@interface ClassA
@property (readwrite, retain) id anObject;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize anObject;

- (void)dealloc {
self.anObject = nil;

[super dealloc];
}
@end

@implementation ClassB
- (void)setAnObject: (id)anObject {
// do nothing!
}
@end
```

I don't see any difference between [anObject release] and self.anObject = nil. 
Because

```
self.anObject = nil
```

is equal to

```
[anObject release];
anObject=nil;
```

Why I don't have memory leak with [anObject release] ?

Comment: Out of context, you are correct with your last lines of code - however the example above clearly constructs a case where `self.anObject = nil;` does not release anything. However, I would call the constructed case pretty much buggy. The original author is correct though, for defensive and robust coding reasons, simply do not use setters for releasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because
>
> `self.anObject = nil`
>
> is equal to
>
> `[anObject release];`
>
> `anObject=nil;`

This is incorrect, and is the source of your confusion.

`self.anObject = nil` does *NOT* translate into a direct ivar access.  It instead becomes

```
[self setAnObject:nil];
```

And since you've overridden the `-setAnObject:` method to do nothing, the underlying instance variable is never getting released, and you are thus leaking memory.

Incidentally, this is **exactly** why you should avoid using setter methods inside your `init` and `dealloc` methods.  Subclasses can override them to do unconventional things.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an object of class B, then your setter doesn't do anything at all. So it doesn't release anObject, so you have a leak.